# UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY The requested action could not be performed

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

We installed the Woocommerce Paypal Payments plugin on our website. We're switching to a different Paypal account (US instead of Canada), which necessitated us to install the new app.

Immediately after switching payments to the new app, about half our customers reported that they were unable to purchase.

This is the error that we're seeing in the backend:

`Failed to process the payment. Please try again or contact the shop admin. [UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY] The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation. <a href="https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED " target="_blank">https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED </a>************************* [UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY] The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation. <a href="https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED " target="_blank">https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYMENT_DENIED </a>********************* Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.`

We have switched back to our old payments setup for now, but we'd like to get this fixed.

I spoke to the Woocommerce Paypal Payments plugin developer. His feedback was:
'The “PAYMENT_DENIED” issue is most likely caused by a bank or PayPal denying the transaction and needs to be investigated by PayPal Merchant Technical Support.
We have no access to the backend logging of PayPal, so we cannot see why this transaction was denied. Please contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support to get this investigated.'

When I submitted a ticket to Paypal, they told me that the cards were declined 'based on risk', which is fairly obviously not the case. We've had customers' cards declined by Paypal due to risk in the past. It looks nothing like this.

It seems that there is probably an issue with this new Paypal account. Does anyone know what might be going on?

WooCommerce 7.0.1

WooCommerce PayPal Payments 1.9.5

Comment: I have been facing this problem since start of november. Have you get any fix or work around?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Paypal support has been zero help. We gave up and switched back to our other Paypal account.

Answer (score 0):

> When I submitted a ticket to Paypal, they told me that the cards were declined 'based on risk', which is fairly obviously not the case.

It is the case, the PayPal API returns PAYMENT_DENIED when PayPal has rejected the transaction, generally due to it being detected as involving potential fraud or other compliance/risk issues.

For the live environment, since it's a business rather than technical issue, the account's owner can contact PayPal's general customer support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us and inquire about the declines. It helps to have the details of specific payer examples, including their exact amounts, date+times, and any other identifiers

Comment: We've accepted payments through Paypal on this website for about 6 years. Payments declined due to risk are incredibly rare, they almost never happen. 

Then suddenly we installed the new plugin, connected it to the new Paypal account, and about 50% of transactions were being rejected. 

It just seems really unlikely that high-risk payments are the problem here.

Comment: It is what it is, only PayPal can look into such denied payments for you and prima facie there's no technical issue